# Compare consecutive frames to determine direction of motion using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, motion-detection

I need to compare every frame with the previous and determine in which direction the movement has occurred. Is this possible by just getting the difference between the two frames? Will it work with slow motion of about 2 m/s?
Also, how could I calculate direction of motion using the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [optical flow analysis](http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b05/notes/CS%20223-B%20T1%20stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf).

Comment: Using goodFeaturesToTrack() gives a very low frame rate. Neither does FAST do much better. Any suggestions?

Comment: FAST is very, very fast. The next steps of your processing depend on the number of features you select, though. That might be your problem. Try to change the threshold for FAST (use 60 for its parameter, for instance), or select less features. ORB allows you to choose the number of features that will be selected.

Comment: Yes, FAST is really fast. The slowness was because of something else.

Comment: No keypoints are detected when the camera is in fast movement.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [SLAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping) as well.

Comment: Is there an implementation of SLAM in OpenCV?